# How to specify the number of odd and even numbers from a random generator in R?

Tags: r, random

I need to generate a `random` selection of 9 whole numbers from 1 to 40 with the following condition: the output must contain 5 `even` numbers and 4 `odd` numbers.

I have the following code to generate 9 random numbers:

```
x1<- sample(1:40, 9, replace=F)
> x1
  [1]  2 36  6 10 39 17 14 11 25
```

I now need to add the odd and even numbers condition in the equation. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the order of the numbers does not matter, you could try

```
c(sample(seq(2,40,by=2), 5, replace=F), sample(seq(1,39,by=2), 4, replace=F))
```

where `seq(2,40,by=2)` generates the even numbers, and `seq(1,39,by=2)` generates the odd numbers. If the order does matter (i.e. it should also be random), you can wrap the outer `c` with `sample`:

```
sample(c(sample(seq(2,40,by=2), 5, replace=F),sample(seq(1,39,by=2), 4, replace=F)))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: When running the codes where order matters, I get the following error message: Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'

Comment: @user3115933 oops, my bad! Fixed it ;) I replaced `c` instead of wrapping it.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
sample(c(2*sample(0:19, 4) + 1, 2*sample(1:20, 5)))
```